# Doing math on NSUserDefaults and re saving - Not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I am running the following code to save the total bytes sent:

```
NSUInteger bytes = 10;  
int newBytes = bytes+[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"TotalBytes"];
NSLog(@"newBytes %i", newBytes);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newBytes forKey:@"TotalBytes"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"%i", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"TotalBytes"]);
```

The Math seems to work fine, newBytes logs out the correct number, then when I run the synchronise command, the NSLog again returns the correct value. However when this code runs a second time, the key value is still set at its previous value, and hasn't saved.

Am I doing something really stupid here? Help!?!

Comment: Don't call `synchronize`, that just causes unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Also, are you quitting your app immediately after running this code, then reopening it?  If so, the device hasn't had time to save the defaults.  Sometimes it can take a couple seconds for it to rewrite the prefs.

Comment: This code runs on a button press. Everytime the button is pressed there is no change.

Comment: @sudo what's wrong with synchronize?  I thought that's what caused the write to disk?   If the app exits unexpectedly without the synchronize, you'd lose the defaults, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Bogatyr: There's nothing exactly wrong with `synchronize`, if it's truly needed.  However, if an instant sync is not needed it's reccomended to not use it and just let the OS handle the writing instead.

Comment: Well just to add that regardless of synchronise or not, it still doesn't work. It appears to save the NSUserDefault, but on the next run of the code it's forgotten, and back to its original value (of 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mootymoots: there's really nothing wrong in your code, i tried it both in simulator and iTouch, it write and read the new +10 value... i tried also to start my app directly on iTouch (not via xCode) and when i run again via xCode the value was +10 * nTimes i used the app...

so... are you sure that you are writing on standardUserDefaults JUST with this code?

try "menu:edit:find:find in project" in xcode and search for standardUserDefaults...

and you can also try "menu:build:clean all targets"...

Comment: you're right. I was doing something stupid elsewhere! Thanks for confirming my code was ok - I am not mental :)